# Android: How can you tell what style is applied to a widget at runtime

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-view, android-theme

Is there a way to determine what style is being used by a widget at runtime, and to see the style overrides being applied? I had hoped that the Hierarchy Viewer would show this but it doesn't. For example, if you use a theme based on another theme, then override the text color in the layout XML for the widget, is there any tool or method available to see this at a glance, or do I have to determine it from examining the source code and theme/style definition files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this isn't possible.

Styles are an organizational tool that are defined in XML and are compiled into a binary format at compile time. Thus, I doubt that the Android OS would be able to distinguish between the different styles that are applied to your widgets at runtime.

I don't think it is possible to dynamically set a view's style either.